# How to Fix Widgets Blank/Black/Not Working iOS 15

Tags: ios, swift

Since updating to iOS 15, my app widget does not display. it's just a white tile. I can edit the widget and select any data, but no data display. Can you help me restore this functionality?

I already removed app/reboot my phone and try everything but app widgets not showing?

[image: it's looks like this]

Comment: Did you try to debug your Widget Target?
I've had the same issue and in my case it was related to UIImage from Assets catalog. With iOS 15 for some reasons some images started to need more memory, as a result 30 mb memory limit for Widget was exceeded. I've updated compression type to "GPU Smallest Size" to solve it.

Comment: I already try out and image is compressed. but still not working

Comment: images coming from server and once I upload these images from app it's less then 5MB.

Comment: Did you try to run widgets without images?